# how to reformat the factor data in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below,

```
     structure(list(habitat = c("open", "open", "open", "open", "open", 
"open", "open", "open", "open", "open", "open", "open", "open", 
"open", "open", "open", "open", "open", "open", "open", "open", 
"open", "open", "open", "open", "open", "open", "open", "open", 
"open", "open", "open", "open", "open", "open", "overgrown", 
"overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", 
"overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", 
"overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", 
"overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", 
"overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", 
"overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", 
"overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", 
"overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", 
"overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown", "overgrown"), sex = c("female", 
"female", "female", "female", "male", "female", "female", "female", 
"female", "female", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", 
"female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "male", 
"female", "female", "male", "male", "male", "male", "female", 
"female", "female", "female", "male", "female", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "female", "male", "male", 
"female", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "female", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "female", "male", "female"), colour = c("red", "red", 
"red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
"black", "red", "black", "black", "red", "black", "red", "red", 
"black", "black", "black", "red", "red", "red", "black", "black", 
"black", "red", "red", "red", "black", "red", "red", "black", 
"black", "red", "black", "red", "red", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "red", "red", "black", "black", 
"black", "red", "red", "red", "black", "red", "red", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "red", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "red", "red", "red")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-80L))
```

I want to count the numbers based on 'habitat' and 'colour' columns and also reshape the data frame like below (despite the 'sex' column),

```
habitat        red  black

open           24     11

overgrown      14      31
```

How to realise this in r?

Comment: `xtabs(~habitat+colour, data=d)` or `table(d$habitat, d$colour)`.

Comment: Or if you like `tidyverse`, `count(df, habitat, colour) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = colour, values_from = n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the counts based on habitat and colour, assign your data to a data frame and pass those columns to `table()`.

```
table(df$habitat, df$colour)
```